# Symfony 5 routing with annotations doesn't work with Apache and Docker

Tags: apache, docker, symfony, routes, annotations

I'm trying to make a Symfony 5 app running in a Docker (version 19.03.8) with Apache.

I have an issue with the routing of the applications using annotations, Symfony always returns the error `Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /test2"" at /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 136`

It seems to be environment related because it works properly when I use the symfony local web server and when I use a xampp installation in windows.

A really weird thing is that I only get the error if I use the annotations, if I configure my routes with the `routes.yaml` file it works fine.

I installed the annotations with `composer require annotations` and the symfony apache-pack with `composer require symfony/apache-pack`, which created the `.htaccess` file in my public folder

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

This is the content of my controller:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class TestController {

    /**
     * @Route("/test2", name="test2")
     */
    public function test2() {

        return new Response('{"hehe": "working?"}', Response::HTTP_OK, ['content-type' => 'application/json']);
    }
}
```

This is the content of my annotations.yml

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation

kernel:
    resource: ../../src/Kernel.php
    type: annotation
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1

EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /app/public

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libpq-dev zip unzip && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

ADD conf/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/app.ini

RUN a2enmod rewrite
ADD conf/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
ADD conf/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/z-app.conf
RUN a2enconf z-app
RUN chmod -R 755 /app
```

This is my apache.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "/app/public"
<Directory "/app/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This is my vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/app/public"
    <Directory "/app/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried to clear the cache with `php bin/console cache:clear`

EDIT: Inside the container the route isn't listed, but if I run `php bin/console debug:router` outside of the container it works, I have no idea why...

Comment: I didn't touch this part, it was generated by symfony, I guess it was done during the `composer require annotations` command

Comment: can you call `bin/console debug:router test2` in the symfony folder in your docker container and post the output?

Comment: I edited the question, indeed inside the container I can't see the route but outside it works fine. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: one very banale reason would be, that the code inside isn't the same as outside. Can you check that the code is the same?

Comment: Yes it is the same

Comment: well, if the code is the same but the console command won't show the route, then the cache would have to be cleared (in the docker container). Otherwise, I'm really out of ideas. because the console command in the end is a good indicator, that something on the symfony side isn't working correctly. depending on how you include your code in the docker container, this might actually make a difference ;o/

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue which was a bug in virtualbox shared folders.
My setup is a Windows 7 host with a linux VM that runs the container.

`composer install` wasn't working properly because of the shared folders situation (more information https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1240 https://github.com/kylekatarnls/update-helper/issues/3)

I had version 5.X.X of VirtualBox, I upgraded to 6.0.18 and now it's working fine